# ListView item backgrounds not changing

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I have an unusual issue with my `ListView`.  I currently have a "`deselectAll()`" method which iterates through the items in my ListView and sets them to unchecked (the items implement the `Checkable` interface).  The "checked" variable gets changed correctly (the view reports as not being checked), but the visual indicator (in this case, a background change) does not show the view as unchecked (the background stays the color of a checked item).

I am iterating and deselecting through my listview like so (I also added my declerations):

```
private ListView vw_entryList;

private void deselectAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        ((Entry)vw_entryList.getItemAtPosition(i)).setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

The code for my implemented `setChecked()` is as follows:

```
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    _checked = checked;
    if (checked) {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_checked);
    }
    else  {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_unchecked);
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

It should be noted that when the items are clicked, they are toggled between checked and unchecked in the `OnItemClickListener`, and this works ok, with the background change and everything.  The code for toggling is very similar:

```
public void toggle() {
    _checked = !_checked;
    setBackgroundResource(_checked ? 
            R.drawable.listview_checked : R.drawable.listview_unchecked);
    invalidate();
}
```

The only difference I can see is where the methods are called from.  `toggle()` is called from within the `OnItemClickListener.onClick()` method, while my `deselectAll()` is called from within a button's standard `OnClickListener`, both in the same class.  **Does anyone have any ideas as to why the background doesn't change when I call my deselectAll() function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything (thanks for your help Jarek), I found a solution that works for my purposes.  Instead of implicitly calling the `setChecked()` within the view that was clicked, I leave it up to the `setItemChecked()` method within the `ListView` class.

My updated code:

```
private void deselectAll() {        
    for (int i = 0; i < sAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        vw_entryList.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
}
```

My best guess is that the `ListView` knows that its items implement the `Checkable` class, and thus requires itself to be the handler of all item operations.  Something along those lines.  If anyone can explain in more detail why this solution works while the others did not, I'll reward them with the answer and an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have custom, non-standard color for the background? If so you might take a look at http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/22/why-is-my-list-black-an-android-optimization/ - it boils down to setting android:cacheColorHint attribute of your list to the background color. Maybe that will help.

Edited after further discussion:

I think you need to call getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() on the List rather than invalidate(). List is really build in the way that it is relying on adapter to provide the data. What you are doing in fact you have an implicit adapter - Entry is really kept in the adapter and by setting checked, you are changing the data model really, but if you do not call notifyDataSetChanged() the list does not really know that the model has changed and will not recreate the views (invalidate() will only redraw the existing ones).

Comment: The background is a state-list-drawable that I created from XML.  For some reason, I couldn't get the state_checked state working, so I implemented a separate state list drawable called listview_checked, then switch the resources in the code.  Unfortunately, this cacheColorHint attribute did not affect anything, and the link was a good read but I think unrelated to my issue.  It's confusing because changing the background drawable from within the onItemClickListener works fine.  Thanks for the interesting link though.

Comment: I think you would do better then by not changing background, but by simply adding a "checked color" "fill_parent" view to your list item and make it VISIBLE/INVISIBLE when state changes to checked/unchecked

Comment: even after this change (VISIBLE / INVISIBLE switching), the views aren't changing the background.  Hm, I'll keep working at it.

Comment: I think you need to call getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() on the List rather than invalidate(). List is really build in the way that it is relying on adapter to provide the data. What you are doing in fact you have an implicit adapter - Entry is really kept in the adapter and by setting checked, you are changing the data model really, but if you do not call notifyDataSetChanged() the list does not really know that the model has changed and will not recreate the views (invalidate() will only redraw the existing ones). Updating the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the first thing I tried, and yet it still did not update the fields.  The ListView adds and deletes rows OK with notifyDataSetChanged, but the code to hide / show the correct background still didn't get called.  I did find a solution though, I'll post it below.